# "L'art gentil rend / l'argent tyran" : quel épithète pour cette rime ?

Tags: rime

Phonétiquement identiques, quelle qualité attribue-t-on à ces deux vers que l'auteur présente comme "rime riche" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En poésie ce sont des vers holorimes (ou olorimes, je ne pense pas que le h soit nécessaire, en revanche il n'y a pas de "h" à épithète)